# Fast lock and unclock screen by lock button doesn't lock screen at all

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, lock-screens, bugs, samsung-galaxy-s-advance

I couldn't find any topic related to this. If there is one, please flag to delete.

There is problem with lock button that it doesn't lock your screen even when you setted in settings to lock the screen for security.

Sometimes it happens that if you click on this button and immediately click again to unlock, last screen / activity of application is shown again without lock screen.

Step to reproduce

1. Turn on security screen in settings
2. Open your app
3. Click lock button
4. Click fast lock button again
5. Screen of your app is visible as it was, instead of there should be lock screen

How can I fix this bug? Did someone find this problem before?

---

### Bug found on device: GT-I9070 v 2.3.6

I suspect that there is a problem with transition. In my private app I use custom transition by `context.overridePendingTransition(R.layout.fadein, R.layout.fadeout);`.

Of course there is no connection between system android <> custom app. This bug is hard to reproduce. Sometimes you see few times in row and sometimes its impossible..

Comment: Lumma, could you please add some device info (what device are you using, which Android version does it run)? I also have problems as what the "lock button" should be. Described behaviour could be normal, as some devices use a little "timeout" before activating the lock (after switching off the screen), in case you "accidentally" hit the switch.

Comment: @Izzy modified text

Comment: Thanks! I cannot give any closer help here (no Samsung device), but I added two more tags which might help to draw some more attention to your question from those who might.